# ValueError using dask QuantileTransformer : unknown shape (1, nan)

Tags: python, dask

I'm trying to use the QuantileTransformer from das-ml

For that, I have the following DF:

[image]

When I try:

from dask_ml.preprocessing  import StandardScaler,QuantileTransformer,MinMaxScaler

```
scaler = QuantileTransformer()
scaler.fit_transform(df[['LotFrontage','LotArea']])
```

I get this error:

> ValueError: Tried to concatenate arrays with unknown shape (1, nan). 
>   To force concatenation pass allow_unknown_chunksizes=True.

And I don't find where to set the parameter: allow_unknown_chunksizes=True
since in the transformer raises and error.

The first error disappears if I compute the df beforehand:

```
scaler = QuantileTransformer()
scaler.fit_transform(df[['LotFrontage','LotArea']].compute())
```

But I don't why is this necessary or even if it is the right thing to do. 
Also, in contrast to the StandardScaler this returns an array instead of a dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a limitation of the previous Dask-ML implementation. It's fixed in https://github.com/dask/dask-ml/pull/533.

Comment: Dask-ML master (and Dask >=1.1.2).